# Check If Today Is First Of Month

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, ssms

On my search engine I have seen multiple results to get the first day of a month, but I want to do something slightly different.  In SQL 2016, I want to check if Today `GetDate()` is the first day of the month.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IF DAY(GetDate()) = 1
    print 'first of the month'
ELSE
    print 'not first of the month'
```

Or

```
IF DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) = 1
    print 'first of the month'
ELSE
    print 'not first of the month'
```

Comment: all my time i've spent in management studio i never knew about the ``Day()`` function.  I've learned something today, thank you

Comment: @JamesMandatory Wait til you learn about the [`MONTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, you'll need a change of underwear... ;)